# How to use CSS :has selector for nested elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I use the `:has` selector to go multiple levels deep?

I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be supported:

```css
div:has(p:has(span)) {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Hello</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Bye</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to select?

Comment: @j08691 I want to select the parent that has a `p` child, and that `p` child has a `span` child.

Comment: @Shahriar Then David's selector would work

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for pointing that out. And yes, your solution is what I want, wanna post it as an answer so I mark it as the accepted one?

Comment: @j08691 I have a need to check if any element has a certain checkbox checked except if another checkbox is checked. So I want something like `:has(article:has(div:first-of-type input:last-of-type:not(:checked)) div:last-of-type input:checked)`. It allows for checking 2 unrelated conditions together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only need to style the `<div>` if it has a descendant `<p>` element that in-turn has a descendant `<span>` element, I'd suggest:

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}

div:has(p span) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Hello</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Bye</p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v4yxkfcb/).

It's worth adding the caveat that this does not currently work in Firefox (version 111.0.1, running on Ubuntu 22.10). So browser variance and inconsistency is to be expected.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if, say, I want to apply a style to div with class "divA" iff it has a child div "divB" that itself has a child div "divC"?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to original question, `:has` can't be nested. Quoting [MDN](https://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#syntax):

> **The :has() pseudo-class cannot be nested within another :has().** This is because many pseudo-elements exist conditionally based on the styling of their ancestors and allowing these to be queried by :has() can introduce cyclic querying.